# How Minimal solution is obtained as limit of approximations

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

**I have encountered a problem in the proof of a Lemma in an article. The image of Lemma and it's proof is this:**

[image]

**I can understand the proof, but I don't know why this solution which is obtained as a limit of approximations must be a minimal solution ( minimal solution means that this solution at each point is less than or equal with the other solutions).**

**I need only a hint. Thanks.**

Comment: Note the solution one constructed does NOT depends on $ \tilde{u}$ other than the fact that it exists.   So now suppose $ w_0$ is another solution,  note by the iteration procedure the constructed solution $v$ satisfies $ v \le w$.   So it is THE minimal solution... at least i think this is how that goes...

Comment: @Math604, thanks, I was thinking in this way too, but then I suspected that maybe it needs zorn kemma.